# we are getting this error when we start our application + weblogic error

Tags: weblogic

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [FMWGEN][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]INTEGER ?? ???????? ????????? ??? ?????????? ???????.
    at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.dda4.b(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.dda4.a(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.dda3.b(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.dda3.a(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.ddr.v(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.ddr.a(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.ddq.a(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.ddr.a(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserver.ddj.m(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddde.e(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddde.a(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddb9.a(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddde.v(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddde.u(Unknown Source)

Can i Know what deos "weblogic.jdbc.sqlserver.xxx" error means ? and the caused by error, i have never seen INTEGER error.. any inputs would help.

Thanks, 
Brij

Answer (score 0):

As i see you use sql server as database.

Check if jdbc driver for MS sql server is in the classpath of the server.

Check how you defined your db datasoruce.

Comment: Thanks. i did check the class path i have all JAR files in place.

Comment: Thanks. i did check the class path i have all JAR files in place.
But can you help me understand the "INTEGER ????????? ", what does that mean? 

is it that the server is reaching the DB and timeout or is it timing out at server level.

Comment: when you define the datasource you can test it via A test button from weblogic console...try that.